# Sending android data to a PC

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am trying to find a simple way that I can send Android data (collected via accelerometers) in real time to a PC.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You can send data to a server application running on your pc. The sending is done by your Android client app.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Firebase Database. On the PC side, you may use javascript in a browser to access the database.
The advantages of this approach are:

- no data is lost in case of connection problems;
- the PC may be located half a world away;
- there might be many PCs viewing the data, and many phones contributing the data.